# c#の引数について

Tags: c#, unity3d, azure

[Chapter 6 - Create the MicrophoneManager class | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mr-azure-301#chapter-6--create-the-microphonemanager-class)

上記ドキュメントを参考にしているのですが、以下のコードの
`private void DictationRecognizer_DictationResult(string text, ConfidenceLevel confidence)` について質問です。
この関数はなぜ `StartCapturingAudio()やStopCapturingAudio()` 中で引数無しで使用できているのでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;

public class MicrophoneManager : MonoBehaviour {

    // Help to access instance of this object 
    public static MicrophoneManager instance;

    // AudioSource component, provides access to mic 
    private AudioSource audioSource;

    // Flag indicating mic detection 
    private bool microphoneDetected;

    // Component converting speech to text 
    private DictationRecognizer dictationRecognizer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Set this class to behave similar to singleton 
        instance = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        //Use Unity Microphone class to detect devices and setup AudioSource 
        if (Microphone.devices.Length > 0)
        {
            Results.instance.SetMicrophoneStatus("Initialising...");
            audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            microphoneDetected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Results.instance.SetMicrophoneStatus("No Microphone detected");
        }
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Start microphone capture. Debugging message is delivered to the Results class. 
    /// </summary> 
    public void StartCapturingAudio()
    {
        if (microphoneDetected)
        {
            // Start dictation 
            dictationRecognizer = new DictationRecognizer();
            dictationRecognizer.DictationResult += DictationRecognizer_DictationResult;
            dictationRecognizer.Start();

            // Update UI with mic status 
            Results.instance.SetMicrophoneStatus("Capturing...");
        }
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Stop microphone capture. Debugging message is delivered to the Results class. 
    /// </summary> 
    public void StopCapturingAudio()
    {
        Results.instance.SetMicrophoneStatus("Mic sleeping");
        Microphone.End(null);
        dictationRecognizer.DictationResult -= DictationRecognizer_DictationResult;
        dictationRecognizer.Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This handler is called every time the Dictation detects a pause in the speech. 
    /// Debugging message is delivered to the Results class.
    /// </summary>
    private void DictationRecognizer_DictationResult(string text, ConfidenceLevel confidence)
    {
        // Update UI with dictation captured
        Results.instance.SetDictationResult(text);

        // Start the coroutine that process the dictation through Azure 
        StartCoroutine(Translator.instance.TranslateWithUnityNetworking(text));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

左辺値 [`dictationRecognizer.DictationResult`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.DictationRecognizer.DictationResult.html) は[イベント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/)です。関数を使用しているのではなく、後で呼び出してもらうよう登録しているだけです。
そして[プログラムでイベントをサブスクライブするには](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events#to-subscribe-to-events-programmatically)で説明されているように従来から使用可能な書式

```
dictationRecognizer.DictationResult += new DictationRecognizer.DictationResultDelegate(DictationRecognizer_DictationResult);
```

に対してC# 2.0以降で使用できる簡略化された書式

```
dictationRecognizer.DictationResult += DictationRecognizer_DictationResult;
```

が使われています。ソースコードを読む際、コード上は後者となっていますが本質的には前者であることを留意する必要があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。TranslatorクラスでMicrophoneManager.instance.StartCapturingAudio();によってStartCapturingAudio()がDictationRecognizer_DictationResultを呼び出す際に引数(string text, ConfidenceLevel confidence)は必要ないのでしょうか。

Comment: なぜ必要と考えるのか、 @peridotite さんの考えがわからないので、説明できません。もう少し説明してください。

Comment: 「StartCapturingAudio()がDictationRecognizer_DictationResultを **呼び出していない** から **引数を指定する必要が無い** 」というのが納得できていないのでは？

Comment: private void DictationRecognizer_DictationResult(string text, ConfidenceLevel confidence)は使用する際に引数にstring textと ConfidenceLevel confidenceの2つが必要という意味ではないのでしょうか。またStartCapturingAudio()ではDictationRecognizer_DictationResultを登録しているだけであり、使用しているわけではないという理解でよいでしょうか。その場合いつDictationRecognizer_DictationResultを利用しているのでしょうか。すみません、少し混乱しております。

Comment: DictationRecognizer_DictationResultにテキストをどのように渡しているのでしょうか。またStopCapturingAudio()はどのタイミングで呼び出されているのでしょうか。

Comment: @peridotite さん、質問の参照記事に書いてあるような？[日本語版](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/mixed-reality/mr-azure-301#chapter-6--create-the-microphonemanager-class)の記述では`DictationRecognizer_DictationResult`が何時呼び出されるかは「9.次に、音声が停止したときに呼び出されるディクテーションハンドラー...」とあります。`StopCapturingAudio()`はヒントに「このアプリケーションではこれを使用しませんが、アプリケーションでのオーディオのキャプチャを停止する機能を実装する場合は、 Stopcapturingaudio()メソッドもここで提供されています。」とあるので、記事内にはこれを呼び出す箇所は無いのでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

> この関数はなぜStartCapturingAudio()やStopCapturingAudio()中で引数無しで使用できているのでしょうか。

利用できていると言うより、`DictationRecognizer` クラスから 呼び出される関数を `DictationResult` イベントハンドラに登録しています。

そして `DictationRecognizer` クラスが 認識されたテキスト を下記のようにイベント通知すると

```
string msg = "認識されたテキスト。";
DictationResult?.Invoke(msg, ConfidenceLevel.High);
```

イベントハンドラに登録された 複数の 関数が呼び出される仕組みです。

例えば

```
m_DictationRecognizer = new DictationRecognizer();

m_DictationRecognizer.DictationResult += (text, confidence) =>
{
      Debug.LogFormat("Dictation result1: {0}", text);
};

m_DictationRecognizer.DictationResult += (text, confidence) =>
{
      Debug.LogFormat("Dictation result2: {0}", text);
};
```

のように １つのイベントハンドラに複数の関数を登録した場合 下記のようにログ出力されます。

```
Dictation result1: 認識されたテキスト。
Dictation result2: 認識されたテキスト。
```

なぜ このような事をやっているのか？ という事ですが、`DictationRecognizer` クラスで
呼び出し先の 関数を知らなくても 呼び出しができるように プログラムの結合度を最小限にするための よくあるデザインパターンの一つです。　[デリゲートの一般的なパターン](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/delegates-patterns)